# Как одновременно обновить числа в разных фрагментах?

Tags: android

В общем есть Tatbbed Activity с ViewPager в нем, и несколькими вкладками фрагментами:

Фрагмент 1

```
public class fragment_main extends Fragment {

private int iCount;
private TextView mIronTextView;

public static final String APP_IPREFERENCES = "imysettings";
public static final String APP_PREFERENCES_ICOUNTER = "counter";
private SharedPreferences miSettings;


@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_main, container, false);


    miSettings = this.getActivity().getSharedPreferences(APP_IPREFERENCES, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
    mIronTextView = (TextView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.textView44);


    Button mIronCounterButton = (Button) rootView.findViewById(R.id.button4);
    mIronCounterButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {

            if (miSettings.contains(APP_PREFERENCES_ICOUNTER)) {
                iCount = miSettings.getInt(APP_PREFERENCES_ICOUNTER, 0);
                mIronTextView.setText(getString(R.string.iron) + " " +
                        iCount);
            }

            mIronTextView.setText(getString(R.string.iron) + " " + ++iCount);

            SharedPreferences.Editor ieditor = miSettings.edit();
            ieditor.putInt(APP_PREFERENCES_ICOUNTER, iCount);
            ieditor.apply();

        }
    });

    return rootView;


}

@Override
public void onResume() {
    super.onResume();

    if (miSettings.contains(APP_PREFERENCES_ICOUNTER)) {
        iCount = miSettings.getInt(APP_PREFERENCES_ICOUNTER, 0);
        mIronTextView.setText(getString(R.string.iron) + " " +
                iCount);
    }

}

@Override
public void onPause() {
    super.onPause();

    SharedPreferences.Editor ieditor = miSettings.edit();
    ieditor.putInt(APP_PREFERENCES_ICOUNTER, iCount);
    ieditor.apply();
}}
```

Фрагмент 2

```
public class fragment_main2 extends Fragment {

private int PAxeCount, iCount;
private TextView mPAxeTextView, mIronTextView;

public static final String APP_PAXEPREFERENCES = "PAxemysettings",APP_IPREFERENCES = "imysettings";
public static final String APP_PREFERENCES_PAXECOUNTER = "counter",APP_PREFERENCES_ICOUNTER = "counter";
private SharedPreferences mPAxeSettings,miSettings;


@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_main2, container, false);

    mPAxeSettings = this.getActivity().getSharedPreferences(APP_PAXEPREFERENCES, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
    mPAxeTextView = (TextView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.button8);

    miSettings = this.getActivity().getSharedPreferences(APP_IPREFERENCES, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
    mIronTextView = (TextView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.textView14);


    Button mPAxeCounterButton = (Button) rootView.findViewById(R.id.button8);
    mPAxeCounterButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {

            if (mPAxeSettings.contains(APP_PREFERENCES_PAXECOUNTER)) {
                PAxeCount = mPAxeSettings.getInt(APP_PREFERENCES_PAXECOUNTER, 0);
                mPAxeTextView.setText("" + PAxeCount);
            }
            if (miSettings.contains(APP_PREFERENCES_ICOUNTER)) {
                iCount = miSettings.getInt(APP_PREFERENCES_ICOUNTER, 0);
                mIronTextView.setText("" + iCount);
            }



            mPAxeTextView.setText("" + ++PAxeCount);
            iCount-=10;
            mIronTextView.setText("" + iCount);



            SharedPreferences.Editor PAxeeditor = mPAxeSettings.edit();
            PAxeeditor.putInt(APP_PREFERENCES_PAXECOUNTER, PAxeCount);
            PAxeeditor.apply();
            SharedPreferences.Editor ieditor = miSettings.edit();
            ieditor.putInt(APP_PREFERENCES_ICOUNTER, iCount);
            ieditor.apply();
        }
    });


    return rootView;

}

@Override
public void onResume() {
    super.onResume();

    if (mPAxeSettings.contains(APP_PREFERENCES_PAXECOUNTER)) {
        PAxeCount = mPAxeSettings.getInt(APP_PREFERENCES_PAXECOUNTER, 0);
        mPAxeTextView.setText("" + PAxeCount);
    }
    if (miSettings.contains(APP_PREFERENCES_ICOUNTER)) {
        iCount = miSettings.getInt(APP_PREFERENCES_ICOUNTER, 0);
        mIronTextView.setText("" + iCount);
    }
}
@Override
public void onPause() {
    super.onPause();
    SharedPreferences.Editor PAxeeditor = mPAxeSettings.edit();
    PAxeeditor.putInt(APP_PREFERENCES_PAXECOUNTER, PAxeCount);
    PAxeeditor.apply();
    SharedPreferences.Editor ieditor = miSettings.edit();
    ieditor.putInt(APP_PREFERENCES_ICOUNTER, iCount);
    ieditor.apply();
}}
```

Я смог сделать так чтобы число в фрагменте обновлялось при нажатии на кнопку в этом фрагменте, но как сделать так чтобы число одновременно обновлялось во всех фрагментах?

Comment: Эти ваши фрагменты одновременно все присутствуют на экране?

Answer (score 1):

Можно сделать несколькими способами.

1. Через `BroadcastReceiver`. Для этого необходимо задать viewpager'у `setOffscreenPageLimit` равное количеству табов. Тогда ваши фрагменты не будут удаляться, таким образом, если добавить регистрацию этих бродкастов в `onCreate`, а `unregisterReceiver` в `onDestroy`, то они будут актуальны пока у активити не вызывется onDestroy. При изменении числа просто посылаете бродкаст с новым значением числа.
2. Более правильный реализовать [Обзервер](https://www.google.ru/search?q=observer%20java&oq=observer%20&aqs=chrome.2.69i57j0l5.4711j0j9&sourceid=chrome&es_sm=122&ie=UTF-8). Добавить в него фрагменты и говорить им когда было изменено число.

PS Если нужна конкретная реализация пишите в коммент